# Конвертация цикла foreach в lambda выражение, используя Java 8

Tags: map, коллекции, lambda, java-stream, java-8

Добрый день, уважаемые русскоговорящие разработчики. Имеется код, который необходимо отладить в лямбда выражение. Вопрос уже был задан на [англоязычном ресурсе](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39021672/convert-nested-for-loops-to-lambda-expression-using-java-8), но исчерпывающего ответа я так и не дождался. Разве что комментарий, где предлагается сначала аггрегация и затем сборка в коллекцию, где я так и не понял, какой именно коллектор автор коммента имел в виду.
В общем, имея вот этот метод:

```
public Map<Job, Map<Sheet, Collection<JobTransform>>> createPartitioning() {
 Map<Job, Map<Sheet, Collection<JobTransform>>> partitioning = new HashMap<>();
 for (Sheet sheet : content) {
  Map<Job, Collection<JobTransform>> currentMap = sheet.createPartitioning();
  for (Map.Entry<Job, Collection<JobTransform>> entry : currentMap.entrySet()) {
   partitioning
    .computeIfAbsent(entry.getKey(), key -> new HashMap<>())
    .computeIfAbsent(sheet, key -> new LinkedList<>())
    .addAll(entry.getValue());
  }
 }
 return partitioning;
}
```

я хотел бы его преобразовать в лямбда выражение. Все, что мне удалось узнать, это:

```
content.stream().flatMap(sheet -> sheet.createPartitioning().entrySet().stream()).co‌​llect() ...
```

Но как именно написать код внутри `collect()` я, увы, никак не соображу. Буду рад любой помощи и простите мне мой не совсем понятный русский! Долгое время живу за границей и практики именно в "русском языке в программировании" не хватает.

Comment: У тебя достаточно неплохой русский или пользуешься неплохим переводчиком.

Answer (score 1):

Приведу пример на упрощенном преобразовании `(Map<Integer, Map<String, Object>> на Map<String, Map<Integer, Object>>):`

```
Map<Integer, Map<String, Object>> map2 = map1.entrySet().stream()
     .flatMap(e1 -> e1.getValue().entrySet()
                      .stream()
                      .map(e2 -> Arrays.asList(e2.getKey(), e1.getKey(), e2.getValue())))
     .collect(HashMap::new,
             (m, l) -> m.put((Integer) l.get(0),
                     Stream.concat(Stream.of(l.subList(1, 3)),
                             m.computeIfAbsent((Integer) l.get(0), HashMap::new)
                              .entrySet()
                              .stream()
                              .map(e -> Arrays.asList(e.getKey(), e.getValue())))
                           .collect(Collectors.toMap(l1 -> (String) l1.get(0), l1 -> l1
                                   .get(1)))),
             (m1, m2) -> m2.forEach((k, v) -> m1.put(k,
                     Stream.concat(m1.computeIfAbsent(k, HashMap::new)
                                     .entrySet()
                                     .stream(), v.entrySet().stream())
                           .collect(Collectors.toMap(Map.Entry::getKey, Map.Entry::getValue)))));
```

В чистом виде это будет выглядеть вот так, не очень читаемо, но на лямбдах и в одну строчку.

Однако, можно использовать вместо `Arrays.asList` какой-нибудь класс, также выделить некоторые операции в отдельные методы и использовать method-reference, что повысит читаемость, но и увеличит объём кода.
Нужно ли вам такое решение, зависит от вас. На мой взгляд, решение на циклах гораздо более наглядно.